# Need help on removing spaces from my vigenere cipher when it is outputted

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

When I enter "tests are fun" into the text file and read from it to encrypt it I get "ICLAGQPPXKTHCB" instead of "ICLAGNGCYBB" by the way Im using python as the key. What is causing this issue? and when I tried to add an if statement after the convert string to upper I kept getting an error stating that file1 is not defined

**CODE:**

```
Alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ",", ".", "-", " ","\n"]


*def encrypt():
    count = 0
    i = 0
    output = []
    encrypted = []
    keylist = []
    stringlist = []

    **import os
    key = input("Please enter the key you want to use: ")
    fname = input("Enter filename to open and decode: ")
    fname1 = fname + (".txt")
    if os.path.isfile(fname1):
        file1 = open(fname1,'r')
        file1 = file1.read()
        mod = fname + ("_e.txt")
        file2 = open(mod,'w')
    else:
        print()
        print("file doesnt exist try again")
        return()


for index, letter in enumerate(file1):
    if letter.isalpha():
        number = alphabet.index(letter)
        cw = key[index % len(key)]
        shift = alphabet.index(cw)
        nli = (number + shift) % 26
        nl = alphabet[nli]
        output += nl
    else:
        output += letter


   # main function
if __name__ == '__main__':       
       main()*
```

Comment: Counting the comparison of output characters you have and your looking for it seems that you don't want to use the " " in your test, or remove those before passing the code through. This should remove the 3 extra characters, and may resolve the issue.

Comment: So what do I need to add to the code to remove the extra characters? @Jeremie

Comment: There are a number of things you could do, but I think the easiest fix would be to add a conditional where you skip over the space characters. Where you iterate over the characters in your file, add something like this: `if i != " ":` and then continue with the building of your stringlist variable. This will result in a different number of entries than the number in your stringlength variable, so you will need to make some adjustments below as well.

Comment: I changed the code above, I am getting spaces now but getting the wrong letters for conversion. Output:
 
The encoded text is: iclag ppx thc

Comment: You do have the correct number of characters output now, but your not wanting the spaces, so remove your else command. As for the letters not being correct, I think you must of accidentally changed the algorithm as you had the first 5 being calculated correctly the first time. Make sure you kept the algorithm you had intact and try running it again.